# Extract multiple patterns from a URL string

Tags: ruby

I have a URL string:

```
http://localhost:3000/user/event?profile_id=2&profile_type=UserProfile
```

I want to extract "2" and "UserProfile", where these can change.

I tried to use both `match` and `scan` but neither is returning results:

```
url = "http://localhost:3000/user/event?profile_id=2&profile_type=UserProfile"
m = /http(s)?:\/\/(.)+\/user\/event?profile_id=(\d)&profile_type=(\w)/.match(url)
=> nil 

url.scan /http(s)?:\/\/(.)+\/user\/event?profile_id=(\d)&profile_type=(\w)/
=> []
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: In your specific regular expression, you need to escape the ? between event and profile_id, so it's event\?profile_id and you'll have an actual MatchData object. Now you need to remove the parentheses from (s) and (.) and add + to the (\w) so it's (\w+) and you'll get your desired results.

Comment: Don't use a regex for this. They're too fragile to handle URLs which can change order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a pattern to try to do this. URL ordering of the query parameters can change, and isn't position dependent, which would instantly break a pattern.

Instead, use a tool designed for the purpose, like the built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/user/event?profile_id=2&profile_type=UserProfile')

Hash[URI::decode_www_form(uri.query)].values_at('profile_id', 'profile_type') 
# => ["2", "UserProfile"]
```

By doing it that way you are guaranteed to always receive the right value in the expected order, making it easy to assign them:

```
profile_id, profile_type = Hash[URI::decode_www_form(uri.query)].values_at('profile_id', 'profile_type')
```

Here are the intermediate steps so you can see what's happening:

```
uri.query # => "profile_id=2&profile_type=UserProfile"
URI::decode_www_form(uri.query) # => [["profile_id", "2"], ["profile_type", "UserProfile"]]
Hash[URI::decode_www_form(uri.query)] # => {"profile_id"=>"2", "profile_type"=>"UserProfile"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
match = url.match(/https?:\/\/.+?\/user\/event\?profile_id=(\d)&profile_type=(\w+)/)
p match.captures[0] #=> '2'
p match.captures[1] #=> 'UserProfile'
```

In your expression:

```
/http(s)?:\/\/(.)+\/user\/event?profile_id=(\d)&profile_type=(\w)/
```

EVERYTHING you put inside () is captured in a regular expression. There's no need to put the s in parentheses because ? will act only on the preceding character. Also, there's no need for the (.) because, again, the + will act only on the preceding character. Also, (\w) should be (\w+) which basically says: One or more characters (and 'UserProfile' is 1 or more characters.

Comment: So what did I miss just the second non-capturing group?

Comment: "EVERYTHING you put inside () is captured in Ruby". That's not Ruby specific, it's true of regex in general. As soon as you see `(?...)` the parenthesis become non-capturing.

Comment: I liked the other answer better but I still give this one +1.